# Loading images from tablet local files with JSON

Tags: android, ajax, json, local-files, construct-2

This is my first post here and I've got a big problem concerning the access of local file addresses on tablets.

I'd like to load image files in a game by using AJAX to get a JSON file containing URLs of images. My problem is that **I dont know if it is possible to get local file addresses directly from the tablet folders using JSON.**

**Seems like I should use an URL that looks like this "storage/sdcard0/myImage.png." but I'm not sure that it's actually calling the file. Is it ?**

I'm using Construct 2 because I'm not a coder, so I'm quite limited as for raw JavaScript programming. Please try not to flood me with code :D

Comment: I believe you can, URI can be used for urls and local filepaths: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer !
I'll build a prototype during this week end to verify that it works.
I'll post the results here.

Comment: Is this the correct answer you were looking for?

Comment: I have to test it to be sure but if URI are accepted in the JSON syntax it may be what I was looking for :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can, URI can be used for urls and local filepaths:

[URI | Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html)